# How to get all active session from asp.net application

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, iis

My purpose here is to make sure that all the logged in users should not get logged out if application pool stops or restarts.

One way is that i can use out prox sessions and directly store them in database but this is going to impact application performance so i dont want to do that.

Another way i found is that, i can register a "IRegisteredObject" implemented class object in hosting environment.

```
public class SessionTracker : IRegisteredObject
{
        //I created this class as singleton and exposed GetInstance method
        public void Stop(bool immediate)
        {
            //Here i want to get all the sessions and store them in database
        }

}
```

Register it in global object

```
public class Global : System.Web.HttpApplication
{

        protected void Application_Start(Object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
             HostingEnvironment.RegisterObject(SessionTracker.GetInstance());

        }
}
```

I want to get all the active session of application so that i can store them in database at the time of application pool restarts or stops suddenly.

Now when my application starts, at that time i will load all the database stored session states again and all the session states will be valid.

Also i found that i can use Session start and Session end events and add sessions in a list object. I am not sure how efficient it will be as it can take more memory in server side.

Please suggest a approach by which i can get all the sessions at once. Or Is it okay if i use session start and session end event of global.ascx.cs file? Is it going to impact memory utilization?

Comment: `One way is that i can use out prox sessions and directly store them in database but this is going to impact application performance so i dont want to do that.` That is what you should do.

Comment: Thanks @mjwills, Do you think it is going to increase memory utilization?

Comment: @mjwills I tested it and all the sessions reference to same object. so no memory problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did further investigation and created a POC to check if it creates copy of Sessions by reference or by value.

What i found is that it creates copy by reference. So technically there is no memory utilization issue if i add their reference in SessionTracker class. Here the complete implementation of SessionTracker class if somebody is interested to know about it

```
public class SessionTracker : IRegisteredObject
{
    static readonly SessionTracker Tracker = new SessionTracker();
    private static readonly Dictionary<string, HttpSessionState> _sessions = new Dictionary<string, HttpSessionState>();
    private static readonly object padlock = new object();
    private SessionTracker()
    {
    }
    public void Stop(bool immediate)
    {
        try
        {
            //store them in database
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }

    public void AddSession(HttpSessionState session)
    {
        lock (padlock)
        {
            _sessions.Add(session.SessionID, session);
        }
    }

    public void RemoveSession(HttpSessionState session)
    {
        lock (padlock)
        {
            _sessions.Remove(session.SessionID);
        }
    }

    public static SessionTracker GetInstance()
    {
        return Tracker;
    }


}
```

Comment: Consider making `_sessions` a `ConcurrentDictionary` to remove the need for the `lock`.